# How to use heroku buildpacks with docker

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, puppeteer

I have a typical Dockerfile that install packages and run the Nodejs web app:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /some-app

COPY ./package.json .
COPY ./packages/api/package.json ./packages/api/

RUN yarn install --production

COPY ./packages/api/dist ./packages/api/dist/

WORKDIR ./packages/api

ENV NODE_ENV production

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]
```

And i'm using puppeteer in this application, so i have to use a buildpack to install all the necessary packages to run puppeteer.

So i'm using this buildpack:
[jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack](https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack)

The problem is that heroku somehow doesn't recognize that buildpack and doesn't run it.

I'm not sure if using buildpacks with docker is supposed to work or not

Comment: Have you solves this issue?